# Share instagram post on my app

Tags: android, instagram

I'd like to let a user share an Instagram post on my app.

I've noticed that Instagram shows a dynamic list of apps that accept its shared content, but I couldn't find the exact way to add my app into that list.

A screenshot with Instagram's share menu:
[image]

As you can see, only WhatsApp is enabled, after I've installed it.
I can confirm that installing other specific apps, such as Facebook's Messenger, would populate this menu.

This makes me realize that there must be some intent filter that these "client" apps (WhatsApp etc') use to say "Hey Instagram, I accept your shared content".
Maybe there's another way.

I'd like my app to be able to do that. How? Thanks!

Comment: And what does Share menu do? Why don't you just setup for your activity to be general share client?(accept actoin send)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The share menu obviously opens WhatsApp (in the attached image), which lets the user send the post to friends/groups.